# Android Studio App startet nicht aber mein Code ist nicht Schuld

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Ich versuche eine Programm zu programmieren jedoch bekomme ich Fehler Meldungen

Hier ist die MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.test;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
      Button test = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
}
```

Hier ist meine activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<Button
android:id="@+id/button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="124dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="124dp"
android:layout_marginTop="152dp"
android:text="Button"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Ich komme einfach nicht weiter weil mein Code ist nicht Falsch aber ich bekomme Fehlermeldungen.

Hier ist die Fehlermeldung:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.test, PID: 8644
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2843)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:159)
    at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:157)
    at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:675)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:692)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:659)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.findViewById(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:479)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:214)
    at com.example.test.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:20)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:69)
    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:41)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1215)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2831)
```

Comment: Please translate your question to english - the language of this site. Otherwise many people woulnd't be able to understand your question. Do this with the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58240345/edit) button above.

Comment: "mein Code ist nicht Falsch" - wrong premise

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't use `findViewById` outside of a method.

Please implement `onCreate` for your Activity class and put that in there.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
      Button test;

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
         test = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button)
      } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works